# Getting NoClassDefFound Error even when JAR has the Required Class

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a Flink Streaming application which uses Flink 1.14.3. I'm seeing random `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/security/scram/internals/ScramSaslClient` and `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/security/scram/internals/ScramMessages` errors. These are intermittent and don't happen to all jobs. I do see the classes present in the JAR that I'm submitting to Flink.

```
> jar -tf target/streaming-1.4.0.jar| grep ScramMessages
org/apache/kafka/common/security/scram/internals/ScramMessages.class
```

```
> jar -tf target/streaming-1.4.0.jar| grep ScramSaslClient
org/apache/kafka/common/security/scram/internals/ScramSaslClient.class
```

The maven dependency tree looks like this:

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.27:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:jar:2.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-jul:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.flink:flink-table-api-java:jar:1.14.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.flink:flink-table-common:jar:1.14.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.flink:flink-connector-files:jar:1.14.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.flink:flink-shaded-asm-7:jar:7.1-14.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.flink:flink-shaded-force-shading:jar:14.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.flink:flink-table-api-java-bridge_2.11:jar:1.14.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.flink:flink-java:jar:1.14.3:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.11:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.flink:flink-connector-kafka_2.11:jar:1.14.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.flink:flink-connector-base:jar:1.14.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.github.luben:zstd-jni:jar:1.4.5-6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.lz4:lz4-java:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.7.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.flink:flink-streaming-java_2.11:jar:1.14.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.flink:flink-core:jar:1.14.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.flink:flink-annotations:jar:1.14.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.flink:flink-metrics-core:jar:1.14.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.esotericsoftware.kryo:kryo:jar:2.24.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.esotericsoftware.minlog:minlog:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.21:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.flink:flink-file-sink-common:jar:1.14.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.flink:flink-runtime:jar:1.14.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.flink:flink-rpc-core:jar:1.14.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.flink:flink-rpc-akka-loader:jar:1.14.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.flink:flink-queryable-state-client-java:jar:1.14.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.flink:flink-hadoop-fs:jar:1.14.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.flink:flink-shaded-netty:jar:4.1.65.Final-14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.flink:flink-shaded-jackson:jar:2.12.4-14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.flink:flink-shaded-zookeeper-3:jar:3.4.14-14.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.24.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.flink:flink-scala_2.11:jar:1.14.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:jar:2.11.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.11.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:jar:2.11.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.11:jar:1.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.11:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.twitter:chill_2.11:jar:0.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.twitter:chill-java:jar:0.7.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.flink:flink-shaded-guava:jar:30.1.1-jre-14.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.flink:flink-clients_2.11:jar:1.14.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.flink:flink-optimizer:jar:1.14.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:jar:2.17.0:runtime
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.17.0:runtime
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.17.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.22:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.12.5:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.12.5:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.12.5:compile
[INFO] +- com.rivian.rdata:ingestion-common:jar:0.1.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:31.0.1-jre:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:failureaccess:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:jar:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:jar:3.12.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.3:compile
```

Can someone help with this issue if they know of a solution?

Comment: If the jar is loaded by a different classloader than the one running the app, there may be an issue with the latter seeing the former.

Comment: But the deployment environment is the same when these errors sometimes happen and sometimes don't. The only change I made during these runs is adding a log and removing a log statement. Its not even that the log made any difference. Its behaving that way either way.
Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Sorry, it’s too vague to be solved here. There could be many reasons including differences among your hosts where the application is running.